# Fragment life cycle on configuration change

Tags: android

I am new to android. Can anyone explain the life cycle of fragments, on screen rotation? And explain each one of those (like onAttach, onCreateView etc.)

Comment: Visit this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

Just read the official guide of Android http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle. It expains very clearly about the lifecycle of `Fragment` and how to coordinate with an `Activity`.